# How to focus a wx.Notebook Page when right clicking on it

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I have a `Notebook` class with some tabs/pages (inheriting from `wx.Panel`).

I currently detect a right click from within the `Notebook` class and everything works fine. The only problem is that I'd like to set the focus on a particular tab when I right click on it.

How can I do that? The only way I was able to do that is by left clicking on it.

**TabContent** class:

```
class TabContent(wx.Panel) :
def __init__(self, parent, id) :
    # Calls the constructor for wx.Panel
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent, id = id)

    # Creates a vertical sizer
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    # Creates an empty multi-line wx.TextCtrl
    textArea = wx.TextCtrl(self, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)

    # Adds the text area to the sizer
    sizer.Add(textArea, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 2)

    # Sets the previously created sizer as this panel's sizer
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

**Notebook** class:

```
class Notebook(wx.Notebook) :
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        wx.Notebook.__init__(self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.BK_DEFAULT)

        # Initialises tab number to 1
        self.untitledCounter = 1

        # Adds an empty tab
        self.addTab()

        # Sets up events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.onMouseRightClicked)

    def onMouseRightClicked(self, event) :
        print("Left button was clicked on tab " + str(self.GetCurrentPage().GetId()))
```

Answer (score -1):

@Michael,

Try calling SetFocus() in the event handler for the page.

Comment: How? I want to focus it when I right click on it, however I have already tried it and it doesn't work.

The only "working method" for me is left clicking on a tab, then it gets selected and of course the focus is on it. Is there a way to do it by right clicking instead? 

Is there a function that, once I click the mouse, gets the object under the cursor coordinates, for example?

Comment: @Michael, so you have a wxNotebook with some pages. Only one page at a time can be selected. IIUC, what you want is to do a right click on the page title and make that page to become selected. Am I right? What if I do a left click on that same page title?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you do a left click it gets selected, but I'd like user to be able to right click on a tab; this will open a popup menu with some options, such as "Close", "Close all", etc. Of course I need some way to identify the tab I clicked on. For example, in _medit_, if you right click on a tab it doesn't get focused but you can close it.

Answer (score -1):

You can find which tab was clicked on using the Notebook's `HitTest` method, and then if you want that tab to be activated you can call the Notebook's `SetSelection` method.

Comment: I did this: ```def onMouseRightClicked(self, event) :
            mouseCoordinate = event.GetPosition()
            print(str(mouseCoordinate))
            sel_item, flags = self.HitTest(mouseCoordinate)
            print(str(sel_item))```
but wherever I click, it always returns the same value for `sel_item`.